# MYSQL UPDATE: Is it possible to confirm some fields first?

Tags: php, mysql, updates

I got a query like :

```
"UPDATE snakes_tb 
       SET snake_pic_urls= CONCAT(snake_pic_urls,'*".$newSnakePic."'), 
           snake_default_pic = '".$Set_a_Value_here_only_if_this_field_is_empty_or_equal_to_NO_PIC."' WHERE snake_id={$id}"
```

What can possibly be done to satisfy the `snake_default_pic` field's condition before setting it's value? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
UPDATE snakes_tb 
       SET snake_pic_urls= CONCAT(snake_pic_urls,'*".$newSnakePic."'), 
           snake_default_pic = IF(snake_default_pic = '' OR snake_default_pic = 'NO_PIC' ,'default_pic',snake_default_pic) 
WHERE snake_id={$id}
```

If `snake_default_pic` is empty or equal to NO_PIC then it will be updated to `default_pic` otherwise it will keep the same value

Comment: @ErickBest i've just added the explanation , let me know if its clear now

Comment: What's the last `,snake_default_pic)` for?

Comment: @ErickBest If `snake_default_pic` is not empty and not equal to NO_PIC  then the value will remain the same (think as if it updates the field with the same value that it already has)

Comment: Great... Perfect and worked like VOODOO!... +1 for taking time to explain.

Answer (score 2):

Just update the where to only update where there's no pic:

```
UPDATE snakes_tb 
       SET snake_pic_urls= CONCAT(snake_pic_url,'*".$newSnakePic."'), 
           snake_default_pic = '".$pic."' 
       WHERE snake_id={$id}
             AND (snake_default_pic = '' OR snake_default_pic='NO_PIC')
```

Be aware that you're code is also vulnerable to SQL injection. Prepared statements can help prevent this.

Comment: Am using PDO...Things are cool, laid it down that way just for easy understanding at SO.. Thanx for the reminder

Comment: @Stephen... How is this SQL injection proof?... assuming the Query was in a PHP variable `$q`, the Query will begin like `$q="UPDATE` and then concatenate i.e. `'*".$newSnakePic."`, the `$newSnakePic` is still raw and venomous, mayBe you could explain what you mean for the benefit of others. Thanks