# Is it possible to programatically exclude some fields first before selection?

Tags: php, mysql, select

According to this SO Question: [MYSQL UPDATE: Is it possible to confirm some fields first?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17407987/mysql-update-is-it-possible-to-confirm-some-fields-first/17408069#17408069)

We could do something like this with `UPDATE` in `MySql`:

```
UPDATE snakes_tb 
       SET snake_pic_urls= CONCAT(snake_pic_urls,'*".$newSnakePic."'), 
           snake_default_pic = IF(snake_default_pic = '' OR snake_default_pic = 'NO_PIC' ,'default_pic',snake_default_pic) 
WHERE snake_id={$id}
```

Notice the implementation of the `IF` statement. This method faces off the use of a Sub-query in the query.

However, having that in mind, how could we do something similar using the `SELECT`?

Assuming the following Example:

```
<?php
///The Bad String in with which columns should NOT be selected.
$badString ="_none";
```

In this Query, we  have about 10 `Columns` that might contain the `$badString;`
The Longest way and really impractical in some cases will be:

```
$selectQuery ="SELECT * FROM snakes_tb WHERE snake_is_deadly= 'Yes' AND col1 <> $badString AND col2 <> $badString AND col3 <> $badString AND col4 <> $badString AND col5 <>$badString etc...";
```

This way seems to be more accurate but kinda impractical should there be more than a reasonable number of columns to check against. Considering the `UPDATE`query above with the `IF statement`, what could be the best way to successfully have a `SELECT` query that;
 **1)** Will `SELECT` ALL Rows and Columns, **2)** Display only data in rows that do not have columns with the `$badString`, without having to go the long way?

In other words, `SELECT` only rows where no column has a value of `$badString`

Comment: I don't see the relationship between the first query and the second one. The first one is just checking one column, what does that have to do with checking many columns?

Comment: The point is to **SELECT only rows where no column has a value of $badString**. I used the UPDATE example to show an example of how we could avoid lengthy query lines by providing, shorter, precise and easy to implement queries.

Comment: There's no automatic way to perform the same test against all columns.

Comment: But what do you think could be the other way of doing this??.. supposing I have an enormous number of columns. Any hint is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the simplest I can think of:

```
SELECT *
FROM snakes_tb
WHERE '$badString' NOT IN (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, ...)
AND snake_is_deadly = 'Yes'
```

There's no way to test a column without explicitly naming it in the query. If you don't want to hard-code all the column names in your code, you could use `information_schema` to get the list of columns and generate the query from that.

Comment: thanks. but is there any way possible to avoid enumerating each column?

Comment: You could generate the query dynamically using `information_schema`.

Comment: Thanks... considering this as an option, though still searching for ways to better the codes.

Comment: Settle for this. Thanks again